# Check if list of patterns from file1.csv is present in file2.csv and change records in file2.csv

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have 2 files file1.csv and file2.csv

file1.csv contains only 1 column with hundreds of rows.

```
aaa
ddd
fff
ggg
```

file2.csv contains 5 fields with thousands of rows.

```
aaa,2,3,4,
aaa,2,3,4, 
bbb,2,3,4,
ccc,2,3,4, 
ccc,2,3,4, 
ddd,2,3,4, 
ddd,2,3,4,
ddd,2,3,4,  
eee,2,3,4, 
fff,2,3,4, 
ggg,2,3,4, 
hhh,2,3,4, 
hhh,2,3,4,
```

My task is to check if col1 present in file1.csv matches with col1 in fil2.csv then change the 5th column to Y in file2.csv

Desired output

```
aaa,2,3,4,Y
aaa,2,3,4,Y 
bbb,2,3,4, 
ccc,2,3,4, 
ccc,2,3,4, 
ddd,2,3,4,Y
ddd,2,3,4,Y
ddd,2,3,4,Y  
eee,2,3,4, 
fff,2,3,4,Y 
ggg,2,3,4,Y 
hhh,2,3,4, 
hhh,2,3,4,
```

what i tried is

```
for i in $(cat file1.csv); do awk -F "," '$1==$i{$5="Y"}1' OFS="," file2.csv ; done
```

But I am getting only the matched records but not the unmatched records.

Is there a better way I can achieve this in UNIX using awk,sed or other common utility.

EDIT:
Update question with clear example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do it like that, just awk reads two files is okay:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}a[$1]{$5="Y"}1' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Unsure if the title and the 2nd line is your way of explaining, if you want to get rid of them:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}a[$1]{$5="Y"}FNR>2' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Note if file1.csv could be empty, you should change `NR==FNR` to different file checking methods, like `ARGIND==1` for GNU awk, or `FILENAME=="file1.csv"` etc.

If there're huge data to dealing with, change `a[$1]++` to `a[$1]=1` will slightly improve speed.
Also if you want to keep title (or the 2nd line), then it's better to start change array `a` when `FNR>1` or `FNR>2`. Improve the command yourself, I am sure you got the idea ;)

`NR==FNR` means first file, because `NR` means **N**umber of total **R**ecords now, and `FNR` means current **F**ile's **N**umber of **R**ecords.
`a` is an array to actually save `$1` as keys.
`next` skip other block from executing.

When `NR==FNR` is false, means it's not first file, first block will not be executed.
(You can also use `NR>FNR` before a block to specify it, but since I used `next` in `NR==FNR` block, so it is not necessary.)
Then other directives kick in, `a[$1]` is to judge the key exists in the array `a` or not (by refer the value, literally check `key exists` actually should be `$1 in a`), if it exists, then change $5.
Last `1` is to specify a true value, it's a shortcut for `{print}`.
(Since an expression without a block, will have `{print}` implied, and a block is executed when the afore expression calculated to `true`, for which `1` is always true.)

Comment: I updated my question, my file2.csv has repeated rows. does your solution works for that too?

Comment: @Abhinay can't you give it a test ?

Comment: I actually tried, but the file is really huge and not sure if working.. I will update after getting the result. Just wanted to let you know that records in file2 are repeated.

Comment: Thanks !! It worked as expected..
Do you mind explaining me the logic.

Comment: @Abhinay You can easily search it, or read the doc. However, I updated the answer to explain it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Perl solution

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'BEGIN {%kv=map{chomp;$_=>1} qx(cat file1.csv) } print "$_", $kv{$F[0]}? "Y" : "" ' file2.csv
aaa,2,3,4,Y
aaa,2,3,4,Y
bbb,2,3,4,
ccc,2,3,4,
ccc,2,3,4,
ddd,2,3,4,Y
ddd,2,3,4,Y
ddd,2,3,4,Y
eee,2,3,4,
fff,2,3,4,Y
ggg,2,3,4,Y
hhh,2,3,4,
hhh,2,3,4,

$ cat file1.csv
aaa
ddd
fff
ggg

$ cat file2.csv
aaa,2,3,4,
aaa,2,3,4,
bbb,2,3,4,
ccc,2,3,4,
ccc,2,3,4,
ddd,2,3,4,
ddd,2,3,4,
ddd,2,3,4,
eee,2,3,4,
fff,2,3,4,
ggg,2,3,4,
hhh,2,3,4,
hhh,2,3,4,

$
```